# Lightweight 3D Graphics Engine .NET (Compact and Full Framework)

Tags: c#, 3d-engine

I am creating a GUI for a machine that runs remote (WinXP) or on the machine itself (Windows CE 6.0).

Right now I've created a fast visualisation (read: very simple) of the machine itself. The goal is to make a bit more complex visualisation of the machine and for that I would need a lightweight 3d engine.

The engine should run on both full and compact .net framework (I am prepared to do some porting :). 
What I mean with lightweigt is that it doesn't need shading, lighting, advanced camera's. The Idea is that the whole scene is shown in Isometric perspective.

So what I was wondering is that anyone knows a good engine (open source?) or has some helpfull resources you could share with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/).

> Recently Irrlicht has acquired official .NET bindings, allowing users to develop in .Net languages such as VB.NET, C# and Boo.

There is also [Ogre 3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OGRE_3D) and also [Axiom Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_Engine)

Comment: For anyone searching this now, Irrlicht no longer maintains official .Net bindings. The other Irrlicht community port is also dead.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good question. I have looked as well, and not seen anything. It would be great to see some easy to access great visual effects for mobile, to somewhat compete with other platforms that are getting better looking.

Sometimes with Windows Mobile I feel like I am in the Windows 3.1 days!

Answer (score 0):

TrueEngine 3d sdk may also be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [SlimDX](http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/)